# Am I using the right formula for this question?

Tags: probability

I need to use the Bernoulli Trial formula for this problem and I would like to confirm if I'm using it correctly with this question...

Flip a fair coin $12$ times. What is the probability of at least $10$ heads?

$$C(12,10)(.5^{10})(.5^{2})$$

For above: $C(12,10)$ multiplied by (probability of head over $k$ (which I would assume to be $10$)) multiplied by (probability of tails over $n-k$ in which is $2$).

Please confirm or correct this statement. Thanks!

What changes do I need to make to change it from exactly $10$ to at least $10$??

Comment: A non-mathematical note: "Right" is (most commonly) an adjective meaning correct. "Write" is a verb meaning to put markings on something. I have edited your title accordingly.

Comment: You have the probability of *exactly* 10 heads.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, you should make clear that $$\binom{12}{10}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}$$ is your calculation that exactly $10$ heads are obtained in $12$ tosses of the coin.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting *exactly* 10 heads is 
$$C(12, 10) \cdot  0.5^{10} \cdot 0.5^2$$
but you're tasked with the probability of getting *at least* 10 heads. So, you should also consider the probability of getting exactly 11 and exactly 12 heads. Those probabilities can be found in a similar fashion to what you provided.

Your event -- "at least 10 are heads" can now be expressed as a disjoint union of three smaller events -- "exactly 10 are heads," "exactly 11 are heads," and "exactly 12 are heads." Since these are disjoint, the sum of their probabilities gives you the desired result.